# Compute Variance in each column between certain number of rows

Tags: r, variance

I want to compute the variances for each column of a matrix, but that variance must be calculated every 7 rows, for example

```
9.8  4.5  0.9  7.8.....
5.4  9.8  1.2  3.5....
3.1  2.6  9.5  7.1.....
3.4  NA   1.1  1.5.....
7.9  5.9  3.4  2.6.....
4.5  5.1  7.4  NA.....
VAR  VAR  VAR  VAR
```

VAR is the variace of the column.
After 7 rows in the same matrix I have to compute the variance again, removing the NA´s. The dimension of the matrix is 266x107.

I tried with the colVars from the boa package, but that command compute the variance for the entire column.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `data.table` approach:

```
require(data.table)
# Create the data table
dt <- as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(266*107), 266, 107))
# For every 7 rows, calculate variance of each column, ignoring NAs
dt[, lapply(.SD, var, na.rm=T), by=gl(ceiling(266/7), 7, 266)]
```

Comment: My answer is slightly slower.

Comment: I tried this, but my R said it has no `data.table` package.

Answer (score 0):

`aggregate()` is a mighty function for this kind of tasks, no need for another package in this case:

```
lolzdf <- matrix(rnorm(266*107), 266, 107)
    n<-7 
    aggregate(lolzdf,list(rep(1:(nrow(lolzdf)%/%n+1),each=n,len=nrow(lolzdf))),var,na.rm=TRUE)[-1];
```